# Matlab: Generating Random Numbers

Tags: matlab, random

Generating random numbers is simple, but how can I format my code so that the random number is generated *without* decimal points, i.e., automatically rounded up or down?

Comment: If you like the answer, please accept it, so people in the future would know that this is the correct approach

Answer (score 4):

Use the function [`randi()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/randi.html).

You have a easy and interesting tutorial in [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/random-integers.html) link.

Also, if you REALLY want to generate floating point numbers and round them, just use the [`round()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/round.html) function

**EDIT** As Luis suggested, use floor or ceil instead of round!

Comment: I suggest `ceil` or `floor` rather than `round`. so that the rounded numbers be equiprobable

Comment: Agreed with Luis, if you use round you won't get a uniform distribution but will have lower probabilities at the edges. Don't use round for this!